# mysql sum one table but different type

Tags: mysql, sql, select

**task_payments**

[image: task_payments]

```
SELECT t.id AS task_id, t.name, t.created_at
       ,COALESCE(SUM(tp1.amount),0) AS paid
       ,COALESCE(SUM(tp2.amount),0) AS paid_back
       FROM tasks AS t
       LEFT JOIN task_payments AS tp1 ON tp1.task_id=t.id AND tp1.type='1'
       LEFT JOIN task_payments AS tp2 ON tp2.task_id=t.id AND tp2.type='0'
       WHERE t.customer_id='4'
       GROUP BY tp1.task_id, tp2.task_id
       ORDER BY t.id ASC
```

Hi, There is two type(1 OR 0) on task_payments. type 0 is paid back. type 1 is paid. I want separately total amount as result. so I want result; 
task_id=5
paid=450
paid_back=10
I should use join. If there is a filter request, I am going to use paid and paid_colums on where clause. ex: and paid_back>0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe the following query may help you `:D`

```
SELECT  x.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT  a.task_id,
                SUM(CASE WHEN b.type = 1 THEN b.amount ELSE 0 END) paid,
                SUM(CASE WHEN b.type = 0 THEN b.amount ELSE 0 END) paidBack
        FROM    tasks a
                LEFT JOIN task_payments b
                    ON a.id = b.task_id
        -- WHERE a.customer_id = 4
        GROUP BY a.task_id
    ) x
-- WHERE    x.paid > 100   -- sample Request
```

Comment: I have two table and I want getting task_id from tasks table.

Comment: @JW. I allowed myself to edit the post and make a small correction.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan i going to roll it back, since the original query posted by the OP has this condition `tp1.task_id=t.id`

Answer (score 1):

Apart from JW's answer I would like to suggest one thing,

If your requirement is to default nulls then go for

```
nvl(sum(field),0) instead of COALESCE(SUM(tp1.amount),0)
```

If your db doesnt support `nvl` then go for `IFNULL`

Hope this also helps you :)